# Python - nested dictionary. Where is the bug?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a CSV file that I've filtered into a list and grouped. Example:

```
     52713
     ['52713', '', 'Vmax', '', 'Start Value', '', '\n']
     ['52713', '', 'Vmax', '', 'ECNumber', '1.14.12.17', '\n']
     ['52713', 'O2', 'Km', 'M', 'Start Value', '3.5E-5', '\n']
     ['52713', 'O2', 'Km', 'M', 'ECNumber', '1.14.12.17', '\n']
     52714
     ['52714', '', 'Vmax', '', 'Start Value', '', '\n']
     ['52714', '', 'Vmax', '', 'ECNumber', '1.14.12.17', '\n']
     ['52714', 'O2', 'Km', 'M', 'Start Value', '1.3E-5', '\n']
     ['52714', 'O2', 'Km', 'M', 'ECNumber', '1.14.12.17', '\n']
```

From this, I create a nested dictionary with the structure:

```
   dict = ID number:{Km:n, Kcat:n, ECNumber:n}
```

...for every ID in the list.

I use the following code to create this dictionary

```
    dict = {}

    for key, items in groupby(FilteredTable1[1:], itemgetter(0)):
        #print key
        for subitem in items:
            #print subitem
            dict[subitem[EntryID]] = {}
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['EC'] = []
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['Km'] = []
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['Kcat'] = []
            if 'ECNumber' in subitem:
                dict[subitem[EntryID]]['EC'] = subitem[value]

            if 'Km' in subitem and 'Start Value' in subitem:
                dict[subitem[EntryID]]['Km'] = subitem[value]
                #print subitem
```

This works for the ECNumber value, but not the Km value. It can print the line, showing that it identifies the Km value as being present, but doesn't put it in the dictionary.

Example output:

```
    {'Km': [], 'EC': '1.14.12.17', 'Kcat': []}
```

Any ideas?

Ben

Comment: Why downvote it, and then leave no explanation? Is the answer simple?

Comment: What is the content of `value`?

Comment: @Matthias Just an index for the list. In this case the integer 6. I've tried replacing value with 6. No luck.

Comment: @BlackVegetable since when!?... SO exists to assist programmers with errors with their code. It's questions that don't show code/come across as "write this for me" that aren't well received. The OP has posted code, some data etc... This is a perfectly valid question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your inner `for` loop keeps reinitializing `dict[subitem[EntryID]]` even though it may already exist. That's fixed in the following by explicitly checking to see if it's already there:

```
dict = {}

for key, items in groupby(FilteredTable1[1:], itemgetter(0)):
    #print key
    for subitem in items:
        #print ' ', subitem
        if subitem[EntryID] not in dict:
            dict[subitem[EntryID]] = {}
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['EC'] = []
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['Km'] = []
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['Kcat'] = []

        if 'ECNumber' in subitem:
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['EC'] = subitem[value]

        if 'Km' in subitem and 'Start Value' in subitem:
            dict[subitem[EntryID]]['Km'] = subitem[value]
            #print subitem
```

However this code could be made more efficient by using something like the following instead, which avoids recomputing values and double dictionary lookups. It also doesn't use the name of a built-in type for a variable name, which goes against the guidelines given in the [*PEP8 - Style Guide for Python Code*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It also suggests using CamelCase only for class names, not for variable names like `FilteredTable1` — but I didn't change that.

```
adict = {}

for key, items in groupby(FilteredTable1[1:], itemgetter(0)):
    #print key
    for subitem in items:
        #print ' ', subitem
        entry_id = subitem[EntryID]
        if entry_id not in adict:
            adict[entry_id] = {'EC': [], 'Km': [], 'Kcat': []}

        entry = adict[entry_id]
        if 'ECNumber' in subitem:
            entry['EC'] = subitem[value]

        if 'Km' in subitem and 'Start Value' in subitem:
            entry['Km'] = subitem[value]
            #print subitem
```

Actually, since you're building a dictionary of dictionaries, it's not clear that there's any advantage to using `groupby` to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this to follow-up and extend on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038190/355230).

For starters, you could streamline the code a little further by eliminating the need to check for preexisting entries simply making the dictionary being created a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) `dict` subclass instead of a regular one:

```
from collections import defaultdict
adict = defaultdict(lambda: {'EC': [], 'Km': [], 'Kcat': []})

for key, items in groupby(FilteredTable1[1:], itemgetter(0)):
    for subitem in items:
        entry = adict[subitem[EntryID]]
        if 'ECNumber' in subitem:
            entry['EC'] = subitem[value]

        if 'Km' in subitem and 'Start Value' in subitem:
            entry['Km'] = subitem[value]
```

Secondly, as I mentioned in the other answer, I don't think you're gaining anything by using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) to do this — except making the process more complicated than needed. This is a because basically what you're doing is making a dictionary-of-dictionaries whose entries can all be randomly accessed, so there's no benefit in going to the trouble of grouping them before doing so. The code below proves this (in conjunction with using a `defaultdict` as shown above):

```
adict = defaultdict(lambda: {'EC': [], 'Km': [], 'Kcat': []})

for subitem in FilteredTable1[1:]:
    entry = adict[subitem[EntryID]]
    if 'ECNumber' in subitem:
        entry['EC'] = subitem[value]

    if 'Km' in subitem and 'Start Value' in subitem:
        entry['Km'] = subitem[value]
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I've not come across defaultdict before. Very useful to know.